# How to show that $ a^n> b $ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $a > 1$, $b > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am a bit embarrassed to be asking this question, but nevertheless:  it seems evident that for $a > 1$, $b > 0$ (with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n > b$, but I am having difficulty proving it.  Indeed, it seems to me that it must be a consequence of the Archimedean property.  For assume the contrary.  Certainly we can find $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ka > b$, but this only pushes the problem the back one level, as it were:  now we need to show that there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m \geq k$.

I assume that I'm experiencing some sort of strange psychological block against seeing the obvious, but nevertheless:  a gentle hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The previous hint assumes some big stuff about log's which probably relies on facts like the one we've got to prove. I suggest that a good first step is to prove by induction that $(1+x)^n>1+nx$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan  I'm afraid the text I'm using (Baby Rudin) hasn't yet introduced logarithms.

Comment: I understand. Try to work out the one that is suggested. Maybe that can help.

Comment: @ancient mathematician That's a good hint to the OP. I like it. With that, I withdraw my suggestion.

Comment: @solitaireartist In case you don't know how to use the hint, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Thanks.  I think I've got it, but I'll let you know.

Comment: @ancient mathematician: Bernoulli's inequality is even true for $x>-1$

Comment: @Bernard : perhaps, but we need it for $x>0$ here.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you.  I have completed the proof.  Would you like to write up an answer so that I can accept it and you can receive the reputation?

Comment: @solitaireartist you write it up and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first assert that for any $x > 0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $(1+ x)^n \geq 1 + nx$.  Clearly the inequality holds for $n = 1$.  So assume we've proved the proposition for all natural numbers up to $n - 1$.  We have
        \begin{align}
  (1 + x)^n & = (1 + x)^{n-1}(1 + x)\\
  & \geq (1 + (n-1)x)(1 + x)\\
  & = 1 + nx + (n-1)x^2\\
  & \geq 1 + nx.
  \end{align}
        Now let $a > 1, b> 0$.  Then $a = 1 + a'$ for some $a' > 0$.  By the Archimedean property, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ka' > b$.  So we have
        \begin{align}
  a^k & = (1+a')^k\\
  & \geq 1 + ka'\\
  & > b
  \end{align}
as desired.